# MySQL: Where can AND / OR / XOR be used as anything other than logical operators in WHERE clauses?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have noticed that the MySQL logical binary operators (`AND`, `OR` and `XOR`) not always act as such. In particular, `AND` can appear as part of a `BETWEEN ... AND ...` expression.

Besides `BETWEEN`, is there any other case where any of these three tokens (words) can appear as part of a `WHERE` clause but not act as a logical operator?

Comment: Some context: I'm building a simplistic (My)SQL parser in order to optimize WHERE clauses. In a nutshell, I want to take conditions which look like ```(A OR B) AND X AND Y``` and rewrite them as a union of several queries, like ```A AND X AND Y ... UNION ... B AND X AND Y```. (The reason is that ```A``` and ```B``` can each benefit from a different index, whereas ```A OR B``` can not). 

Besides taking into account parentheses, precedence and strings, this is the other pitfall I have identified. I would like to know if there is any other corner case similar to ```BETWEEN```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AND` in `BETWEEN .. AND` is not the same thing as the `AND` operator. It just reuses the same keyword. I'm looking at [jOOQ's](https://www.jooq.org)'s parser source code, and I can tell you there are at least (far from exhaustive):

#### AND

- In window function frame clauses, such as `ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING`
- In the `MERGE` statement's `WHEN` clauses (not supported by MySQL 8 yet), such as `WHEN [ NOT ] MATCHED [ AND ... ] THEN`
- In the `X BETWEEN Y AND Z` predicate
- In the temporal query `FOR PORTION OF .. BETWEEN .. AND` syntax (not supported by MySQL 8 yet)

#### OR

- In `CREATE OR REPLACE` statements, such as `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`

#### NOT

- `NOT NULL` predicate
- `NOT LIKE` predicate
- `IF NOT EXISTS` clause in DDL and a lot of other DDL clauses, like `SET NOT NULL`, `DROP NOT NULL`, etc. etc.

#### Other tokens

- There are also "soft matches", which may be relevant if your "parser" is not smart enough to actually parse the SQL language. These may include functions like `BIT_AND()`

#### Conclusion for your use case

SQL is not a trivial language to parse. A minimalistic parser cannot easily transform all sorts of boolean expressions (or other things) to produce "equivalent" unions. This is *very hard*! Your case may not be correct, depending on the projection. E.g. these two queries are not the same:

```sql
-- May produce duplicate values for col
SELECT col
FROM t
WHERE (a OR b) AND x AND y

-- Does not produce duplicate values for col
SELECT col
FROM t
WHERE a AND x AND y
UNION
SELECT col
FROM t
WHERE b AND x AND y
```

`UNION ALL` cannot be used here because then you'd get too many duplicates that you didn't get before. You'd have to produce this query (akin to what Oracle does when it applies the "concatenation transformation" e.g. via the `/*+USE_CONCAT*/` hint):

```sql
SELECT col
FROM t
WHERE a AND x AND y
UNION ALL
SELECT col
FROM t
WHERE b AND x AND y AND NOT (a AND x AND y) -- Exclude previous UNION subquery predicate here
```

This will get more complicated as your boolean expressions get more complex.

But have you really gained anything? Hard to say. Have you possibly broken your query? Probably, because what happens if you already have a `UNION`? Or `ORDER BY`? Or `DISTINCT`? Or `LIMIT`?

Comment: Hi Lukas, many thanks for your answer. I have accepted it.

My use case is a bit more convoluted than what I said above, but a few answers to your questions:

1) I'm aware the AND&friends in the other predicates are not operators, that's why I mention "tokens".
2) As stated in the original question, I'll be dealing only with WHERE clauses, not full queries, which removes a lot of the potential problems you mention.
3) Queries always include the primary key, so the union should yield the same result set as the original query.

Comment: 4) The tokenization is done by word boundaries (so no confusion with BIT_AND and friends), and NOT is not even considered, as it is an unary operator and does not really influence the result. // As long as I can get the query broken up in an expression tree joined by AND/OR/XOR I should be able to apply logical redistribution laws (or recover the original expression if no optimization can take place). I have some control over the clauses I have to parse, so I can also avoid other pitfalls. Again, many thanks for your detailed answer!